# IOATDMA is not being used by network drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am testing crystal beach dma on x86_64 Intel xeon board. I want to test both e1000e and ixgbe drivers with crystal beach dma.

I have patched ioatdma driver(pci.c and hw.h files ) for crystal beach dma. Now I am facing issue that both drivers do not use this channels at all. The bytes_transferred and memcpy_count are always zero.

Following are the configurations –

Kernel I am using is **2.6.32.431**

```
[root@hvtxrs82 dma]# pwd

/sys/class/dma

[root@hvtxrs82 dma]# ls

dma0chan0   dma12chan0  dma15chan0  dma3chan0  dma6chan0  dma9chan0

dma10chan0  dma13chan0  dma1chan0   dma4chan0  dma7chan0

dma11chan0  dma14chan0  dma2chan0   dma5chan0  dma8chan0
```

I have inserted both e1000e and ixgbe drivers. And dmachannels show that.

```
[root@hvtxrs82 dma]# cat /sys/class/dma/dma0chan0/in_use
4
```

lspci ouput -

```
80:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 0 (rev 04)

80:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 1 (rev 04)

80:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 2 (rev 04)

80:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 3 (rev 04)

80:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 4 (rev 04)

80:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 5 (rev 04)

80:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 6 (rev 04)

80:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ivytown Crystal Beach DMA Channel 7 (rev 04)
```

I have changed stack settings as `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_dma_copybreak=1`

```
[root@hvtxrs82 dma]# cat /sys/class/dma/dma0chan0/bytes_transferred

0
```

Same is for all channels. However ethtool shows traffic and packets received. So why is dma channels not getting used?

Answer (score 0):

[Linux disabled net_dma's TCP receive copy offload in December 2013 because of a bug](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=77873803363c9e831fc1d1e6895c084279090c22).

So it's probably a good thing that it's not working.